# multiplying modified colums to form new column

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I want a query like:

```
select tp.package_rate, sum(sell) as sold_quantity , select(tp.package_rate * sold_quantity ) as sell_amount from tbl_ticket_package tp where tp.event_id=1001
```

here the system firing error  while doing the multiplication as

```
sold_quantity is invalid column
```

another problem is that in multiplication I want to use package_rate which got by select query from tp.package_rate but it multiplying with all package_rate of the table but I want only specific package_rate  which was output of select query

What would you suggest? I want to bind this query in gridview . is there any way to do it using ASP.net gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are referring to sold_quantity here :

```
select(tp.package_rate * sold_quantity )
```

The alias is not recognized at this point.You will have to replace it with sum(sales). You will also have to group by tp.package_rate.

Your query should ideally be like :

```
    select tp.package_rate, sum(sell) as sold_quantity , 
(tp.package_rate * sum(sell) ) as sell_amount from tbl_ticket_package tp 
where tp.event_id=1001 group by tp.package_rate;
```

I am guessing that tp.package_rate is unique for a given event_id, from latter part of your question. If that's not the case, the sql you have written makes no sense.

Comment: thanks. problem solved . actually there was no problem. i tried to not use alias name and wrote sum(sell) again  in multiplication . actually I m doing many calculation and retrieving data using subqueries to calculate sum(sell) and the problem was at the multiplication when finding sum(sell) , I was giving particular package ID in subquery so the multiplication happened with the output of that ticket sold .means there was no problem of tp.ticket_package_rate .now it's fine.thanks